# How can I test an input condition after translating the source code using Coco/R?

Tags: swift, cocor, compiler-generated

I have a function that I want to test in Swift. It has been generated using Coco/R. I have an input statement which I want to test if it provides the desired output using the generated code (Parser.swift).

I haven't tried anything out yet since I don't know where to start.

```
func Addition {
       var x = input.a
       var y = input.b
       let z: Int?
       z = x + y
       return z
   }
```

Expected Result: 
Input File: a = 10
            b = 5
Output: 15

Answer (score 1):

Open XCode , creat new PlayGround:

Then Try this:

```
import Foundation

struct InputFormat {
    var a : Int
    var b : Int
}
func addition(input: InputFormat) -> Int {
    let x = input.a
    let y = input.b
    let z = x + y
    return z
}

let input = InputFormat(a: 10, b: 5)
print(addition(input: input))
```

It was the nearest way to get your code into test.
Hope it helps.